# Prisma: Finding items where two fields have the same value

Tags: prisma

I would like to find items in a Prisma db where the values for two columns are the same. The use case is to compare the 'created_at' and 'updated_at' fields to find items that have never been updated after their initial creation. In raw SQL I would do something like:

```sql
select updated_at,
       cast(sign(sum(case when updated_at = created_at then 
          1 
       else
          0
       end)) as int) as never_modified
  from tab
 group by updated_at
```

Is it possible to achieve this in Prisma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use [Raw Queries](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) to compare time values from the same table.

Here's an example of how you could achieve this, assuming a PostgreSQL database for the following query.

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

async function initiateDatesComparisonRawQuery() {
  const response =
    await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM "public"."Project" WHERE "created_at" = "updated_at";`;

  console.log(response);
}

await initiateDatesComparisonRawQuery();
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use the preview feature [fieldReference](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases/tag/4.3.0) of prisma.

schema.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["fieldReference"]
}
```

your code

```js
prisma.project.findMany({
  where: { created_at: prisma.project.fields.updated_at }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to what [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74591500/6402486) suggests, you can achieve this using `equals`:

```js
prisma.project.findMany({
  where: { 
    created_at: {
      equals: prisma.project.fields.updated_at
    }
  }
});
```